# Seed for $RANDOM environment variable in bash

Tags: bash, random, seed

I am working on a bash script that uses the `$RANDOM` environmental variable as an input in a simulation. The variable does what it say, give random integers, and I as far I understand it is taken from `/dev/random`.

However I would like to have a reproducible simulation, then the pseudo-random generator should be initialized with a seed; is it possible to have a seed for the `$RANDOM` variable in bash?

Comment: From `man bash`: _The sequence of random numbers may be initialized by assigning a value to RANDOM._

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the man page:

```
   RANDOM Each time this parameter is referenced, a random integer between
          0 and 32767 is generated.  The sequence of random numbers may be
          initialized by assigning a value to RANDOM.  If RANDOM is unset,
          it loses its special properties,  even  if  it  is  subsequently
          reset.
```

Note that assigning a value to `RANDOM` actually seeds it; the assigned value won't be the next value returned.

```
$ RANDOM=1341
$ echo $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM
26571 16669 28842
$ echo $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM
14953 18116 2765
$ RANDOM=1341
$ echo $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM
26571 16669 28842
$ echo $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM
14953 18116 2765
```

Comment: How is it that you're not voting to close this as a duplicate? You've definitely answered this before.

Comment: I prefer this answer over what's currently marked as duplicate.